# SSRS Export report to XML and drop <Report> Element

Tags: xml, reporting-services, export-to-xml

I'm trying to set up a report in SSRS with a subscription to export some data as a XML file so it can be imported into another application. However the report element is causing the whole thing to fall over.

My Output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Report xsi:schemaLocation="BO http://reportserver?%2FBO.BILLING%20BacklogTest&rs%3AFormat=XML&rc%3ASchema=True" Name="BO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="BO">
    <ForecastGroups>
        <ForecastGroup>
        <Code>BO.BILLING</Code> 
            <ActualOutstandingTasks>
            <TimeStamp>2015-09-25T00:00:00</TimeStamp> 
                <ArrivalPeriods>
                    <ArrivalPeriod>
                    <StopTime>2015-09-25T00:00:00</StopTime> 
                    <StartTime>2015-09-24T00:00:00</StartTime> 
                    <Tasks>2074</Tasks> 
                    </ArrivalPeriod>
                </ArrivalPeriods>
            </ActualOutstandingTasks>
        </ForecastGroup>
    </ForecastGroups>
  </Report>
```

It doesn't work unless I remove the report element by hand. I need the output to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ForecastGroups>
    <ForecastGroup>
        <Code>BO.BILLING</Code>
        <ActualOutstandingTasks>
            <TimeStamp>2015-09-25T00:00:00</TimeStamp>
            <ArrivalPeriods>
                <ArrivalPeriod>
                    <StopTime>2015-09-25T00:00:00</StopTime>
                    <StartTime>2015-09-24T00:00:00</StartTime>
                    <Tasks>2074</Tasks>
                </ArrivalPeriod>
            </ArrivalPeriods>
        </ActualOutstandingTasks>
    </ForecastGroup>
</ForecastGroups>
```

And then it works fine. Is there a way in SSRS to prevent the report element from rendering?

Thanks,
Greville

Comment: Doesn't work? Does your importing application throw an error? what is it?

Comment: It's looking for ForecastGroups as the first element and states it can't find it if the report element is there. I tried changing the DataElementName property of the report to ForecastGroups and removing ForecastGroup under it. But got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/), the declarative template language used to transform XML content in any way, shape, or form!

Of course you will need an XSLT processor that reads in original .xml file, transforms with below .xsl file, and outputs final .xml file. Practically all modern programming languages maintain XSLT libraries (Java, C#, Python, PHP, even VBA as you can run [xsl transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with your everyday MS Access or MS Excel):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       xsi:schemaLocation="BO http://reportserver?%2FBO.BILLING%20BacklogTest&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True"
       Name="BO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bo="BO"> 
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="bo:Report">
    <xsl:copy-of select="bo:ForecastGroups"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ForecastGroups xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="BO">
        <ForecastGroup>
        <Code>BO.BILLING</Code> 
            <ActualOutstandingTasks>
            <TimeStamp>2015-09-25T00:00:00</TimeStamp> 
                <ArrivalPeriods>
                    <ArrivalPeriod>
                    <StopTime>2015-09-25T00:00:00</StopTime> 
                    <StartTime>2015-09-24T00:00:00</StartTime> 
                    <Tasks>2074</Tasks> 
                    </ArrivalPeriod>
                </ArrivalPeriods>
            </ActualOutstandingTasks>
        </ForecastGroup>
    </ForecastGroups>
```

By the way your original XML's `schemaLocation` path needed the ampersand character `&` escaped as `&amp;`

Comment: Note the SSRS rendering engine already supports XLST, so you could apply that script without needing custom code, e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283112.aspx#XSLTTransformations

Comment: @MikeHoney, even better! So OP has various ways to handle the XML restructuring.